# Android Drive API query

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement query procedure in my app, but the application always finds a result. here is how i set up a query:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
                    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "Foo.txt"))
                    .build();

Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask =
                    mDriveResourceClient
                            .query(query)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                                    new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer) {
                                            Log.i("ARRIVE", "File Found");
                                        }
                                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.i("ARRIVE", "File Not Found");
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
```

No matter what title filter i put, it always finds something. I get "File Found" every time. If I try to access result the app crashes, I am guessing due to the fact there is nothing to access. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do different?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an OnCompleteListener to check whether the task was successful or not as following:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
                    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "Foo.txt"))
                    .build();

Task<MetadataBuffer> queryTask =
                    mDriveResourceClient
                            .query(query)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(MainSettingsBackup.this, new OnCompleteListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<MetadataBuffer> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                          Log.i("ARRIVE", "File Found");
                                        } else {
                                          Log.i("ARRIVE", "File not Found");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```